# how to run apk file in android

Tags: android

I try to run apk file in android, i follo these steps

1. First get the Android SDK and unzip it somewhere on your hard drive
2. Add SDK_ROOT to your system variables pointing to /tools folder under the sdk
3. Run the emulator
4. Copy the apk file to /tools folder
5. Change directory to /tools and run from commandline $adb install your_application.apk
6. Now check applications list in the emulator and you should see the new application installed and ready.

but i will this type of error :

```
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 3):

i think you dont have set proper environment variable .

add path of adb.bat to PATH variable in windows ...

then from command prompt . type adb and check ..... now it  works...

Answer (score 2):

In the new SDK the adb program is in another dir (platform-tools). You'll have to look a bit, but find a binary with that name (you're using windows, right? it'll be called "adb.bat")

Comment: ah, see @nick below: it's platform-tools, not program tools. i'll fix

Comment: Hai nanne... Thanks so much but this steps are already follow but i didn't get ...

Answer (score 1):

From SDK 2.3 the adb. exe is found in {SDK_ROOT}\platform-tools

just open a command window (when in windows) and navigate to that directory
then just type the following:

adb install {path-to-apk}

this only works when there's only 1 device/emulator attached to the computer.
if you want to send it to a device use the -d flag (i.e. adb -d install c:\program.apk)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added it correctly to your system variables?

Look the tools folder up through Windows Explorer en copy the url that's in the address-bar.

Now right click 'Computer' and choose 'Properties'
Choose 'Advanced system settings', go to the 'advanced' tab and choose 'Environement variables'.

Now scroll down the list and find 'Path'. Click 'Edit..' Now go to the end of the line and add ';' and after that paste the url you copied.

Now in command prompt try 'adb' and it should work.

Comment: hai galip...Thanks so much but this steps are already follow but i didn't get ...

Answer (score 0):

copy your apk file to `{SDK_ROOT}\platform-tools` and follow these steps.

1. Run the emulator
2. Copy the apk file to `/platform-tools` folder
3. Change directory to /platform-tools and run from commandline `$adb install your_application.apk`
4. Now check applications list in the emulator and you should see the new application installed and ready.